# Intellij search in .class files hybris project

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to adapt the UncategorizedConditionAdapter in SAP Hybris, but all of its code is in the backoffice.jar.

Sadly Intellij is not searching in .class files.

Is there a way to tell Intellij to search in thouse files too?

The SAP Commerce Plugin has an "hybris Source Code" feature, when importing an project. But it does not decompile the .jar files and scan them afterwards.

Comment: IDE could search in .class files if JAR is added as a library.

Comment: They are already added as library. I can find all the class files by name, but Intellij still does not search in the files.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: SAP Hybris is clossed source, I don't think I am allowed to share.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project with some JAR library added (e.g. gson one)?

Comment: Jetbrains says that is a normal behavior: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000418244-Find-in-Path-Feature-quirks?page=1#community_comment_115000362684 and not going to be changed. The SAP Hybris plugin has a "Hybris source" feature when importing. I thought it would work with that, but it does not

Comment: Yes, search is possible only if sources are added.